# Is MongoDB ChangeStream ResumeToken unique globally?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

As document(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) says, we can resume to get event from MongoDB using resumeToken.

I will store recent resumeToken to common storage, but I'm not sure whether this resume token is unique globally or not.
I want to know it's unique for whole collections or each collection.

It seems to use UUID (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/resume_token.h#L61)..

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by `globally`? Are you referring to tokens from different MongoDB clusters , or are you referring to tokens from multiple collections but from a single MongoDB clusters ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar I mean case from multiple collections in single cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resumeToken` is unique within a single MongoDB deployment cluster. MongoDB [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) utilise a global logical clock. The server encodes the cluster time as the prefix value of a `resumeToken`, resulting in change streams notifications can be safely interpreted in the order received.

Starting from MongoDB v4.0, you can open a change stream cursor for a deployment to watch for changes to all non-system collections across all databases except for `admin`, `local`, and `config`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Our system is v4.0  but fcv is 3.6, so I can not use subscription for database that you said. Thanks!

Comment: @Wan Bachtiar I don't think so. In my experience, if I do a bulk insert to mongodb like within a second 100 documents are being inserted, then in change stream listener the `resumeToken` for each document is not unique. Only 3 or 4 distinct token would be there. I was using version - 3.6