# Getting same resume token in mongodb change stream for concurrently inserted documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, token, azure-cosmosdb, changestream

I have a nodejs function listening to changes (`insert` and `update`) in Azure Cosmos DB’s collection which uses API for MongoDB(3.6) with the help of [**change streams** API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-change-streams?tabs=javascript). Each document received from change stream have unique token(as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-stream-resume-token)). [Please check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072594/10585321)

But the problem is if I'm inserting some documents say 100 or 200 to cosmos db concurrrently, those inserted documents received from the stream have same resume token. This badly afftecs my change stream resume strategy

However this weird behavior is not there in standalone mongodb. I tested and found out that it is happenling only in cosmosdb with mongo api. Is anyone having the same issue? any workaround?

Comment: And what's your strategy?

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide the code to listen to the changes in Cosmos DB with MongoDB Api? I've looked at a lot of resources but can't find anything that worked for me.